Find a value from Range in 2 columns, with additional condition
If I use below formula in G2
=INDEX(D:D,MATCH(1,(F2>=B:B)*(F2<=C:C),0))
The output is first matching condition which is XX
Impage
in G3 I want to add one more condition, first match E3 in column A and then find F3 in range column B-C, so in G3 I want output ZZ

Please clarify your specific problem, what tool is this, google spread sheet, excel?

This is for MS EXCEL
